# Use @RepeatedTest in a test suite

Tags: junit5, test-suite

I have a test suite with multiple test clases in Junit5, one of those clases has some tests that use @RepeatedTest, they do repeat when I run them from that class but not when I run the suite itself, any idea why?

Comment: Which number did you set as argument ?

Comment: 100, but it's the same if I change it

Comment: Build tool? How do you configure the test run? Versions? Small running sample of your issue?

Comment: How have you defined your suite?

Comment: I agree with @MarcPhilipp: please show us your "test suite" configuration.